# unit testing node modules with mocha, module variables acting strange

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

ill get right to business with some code:

**hangman.io.js:**

```
var from = require('fromjs'),
    fs = require('fs');

var defaultBasePath = 'lib/hangman/wordlists';
var filePaths = [];

function init(basePath) {
    basePath = basePath || defaultBasePath;
    filePaths = loadPaths(basePath);
}

function loadPaths(basePath) {
    var wordLists = fs.readdirSync(basePath);
    return from(wordLists).select(function (x) {
        return basePath + '/' + x;
    }).toArray();
}

function getFilePath(type) {
    if (!filePaths || 
        !(filePaths instanceof Array) || 
        !(filePaths.length > 0)) throw new Error('No file paths registered.');
    ...
}

module.exports = {
    init: init,
    getFilePath: getFilePath
}
```

**hangman.io.tests.js:**

```
var io = require('../hangman.io'),
    should = require('should');

describe('io', function () {
    before(function () {
        io.init();
    });
    describe('getLineCount(path)', function () {
        var path = io.getFilePath('test'); //<== this lines throws the exception 
        //"No file paths registered", even tho I have called init() on io.
        var count = io.getLineCount(path);
        count.should.be.an.Number;
        count.should.be.eql(4);
    });
});
```

For those who didn't read the header, I am trying to do unit testing with **[node](http://nodejs.org/)** and **[mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/)** here.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong, why isn't the variable filled with paths after calling `io.init()`.
I use **[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)**, and if i add break points and debug the code i can clearly see that the array is getting filled.
But then afterwards when i call the `io.getLineCount(path)` function suddenly the filePaths variable is empty,
and i ensure you there is no other code going in behind the scenes and manipulate the variable.

I just don't get this, is this a bug or am i doing something wrong, or am I simply an idiot?

I have also tried moving the `io.init()` function inside the unit test itself, also with no different behavior.

Here is a **stacktrace** with modified paths, but everything else is ofc original.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Github\wolfram\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha --recursive --timeout 0 --ui bdd --reporter "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 7.0.2\plugins\NodeJS\js\mocha\mochaIntellijReporter.js" C:\Github\wolfram\test
Testing started at 13:48 ...

C:\Github\wolfram\lib\hangman\hangman.io.js:28
 || !(filePaths instanceof Array) || !(filePaths.length > 0)) throw new Error(
                                                                    ^
Error: No file paths registered.
    at Object.getFilePath (C:\Github\wolfram\lib\hangman\hangman.io.js:28:91)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Github\wolfram\test\hangman\hangman.io.tests.js:52:27)
    at context.describe.context.context (C:\Github\wolfram\node_modules\mocha\lib\interfaces\bdd.js:73:10)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Github\wolfram\test\hangman\hangman.io.tests.js:51:9)
    at context.describe.context.context (C:\Github\wolfram\node_modules\mocha\lib\interfaces\bdd.js:73:10)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Github\wolfram\test\hangman\hangman.io.tests.js:32:5)
    at context.describe.context.context (C:\Github\wolfram\node_modules\mocha\lib\interfaces\bdd.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Github\wolfram\test\hangman\hangman.io.tests.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at C:\Github\wolfram\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:157:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Github\wolfram\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:154:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Github\wolfram\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:341:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Github\wolfram\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:351:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3

Process finished with exit code 8
```

Comment: Can you show the code for io.init ?

Comment: as you can see the my.io.js has a method called init which is exported, I see I have modified the example a little to much, ill fix it.

Comment: Please could you post the code for the `loadPaths` `function` in `io.js`?

Comment: I know that there is no bug with the fromjs library, updated the question with the `loadPaths(basePath)` function

Comment: okay I found the bug here, and it was me who had forgotten to use the `it('should blabla...', callback);` inside the `description()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm sorry for making a big fuss about this. Just been struggeling with this for quite some time now. Guess I was a little frustrated and stressed.

anyways here is the "solution" with my mistake corrected.

**hangman.io.tests.js:**

```
var io = require('../hangman.io'),
    should = require('should');

describe('io', function () {
    before(function () {
        io.init();
    });
    describe('getLineCount(path)', function () {
        it('should return a line count of 4 when type is "test"', function(){
            var path = io.getFilePath('test'); //<== this lines throws the exception 
            //"No file paths registered", even tho I have called init() on io.
            var count = io.getLineCount(path);
            count.should.be.an.Number;
            count.should.be.eql(4);
        })
    });
});
```

This line was missing inside the `description()` functions.

```
The it('should blabla when bla', function(){
    //put stuff to test in here
});
```

I had a lot of unit tests prior to this error not missing the `it()` function, it was probably some mistake as a result of refactoring my tests.